# Trouble Starting up a Daemon written in C with systemctl

Tags: debian, systemd, c, daemon, systemctl

I am trying to register my daemon program that I wrote with C with `systemd`.
I use the following script,

```
[Unit]
Description=App
After=network-target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/daemon
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I use the following commands in order, `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`, `sudo systemctl enable`, `sudo systemctl start`. The program starts normally when I execute it from the command line but doesn't start if I run it through `systemctl`. It is a daemon program which `forks` 2 processes.

And here is the error,

```
Process: 11563 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/daemon (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 11563 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/uhp-service.service
           └─11361 /usr/local/bin/daemon
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Your program exited with status 1. What this might mean, only you know. When does your program returns code 1?

That is, you *do* terminate the main program [returning success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867871/should-i-return-exit-success-or-0-from-main), don't you?

```
int main(...) {
    ...
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Because otherwise what might happen is that `systemd` starts your daemon, your daemon forks, returns failure, and `systemd` performs cleanup - killing the forked threads even if they are running correctly.

Comment: I corrected that, and also had to change `Type=simple` to `Type=forked`. Now it works fine. I had done `if(pid>0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`.